# Problems with atribute components like ngClass or ngStyle

Tags: javascript, angular, web, components

I'm new to Angular 17 and I've noticed that every time I want to use an ngClass attribute or an ngStyle I get an error like it doesn't recognize them and I get this error
NG8002: Can't bind to 'ngClass' since it isn't a known property of 'p'.

atributte.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-atributo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ ],
  templateUrl: './atributo.component.html',
  styleUrl: './atributo.component.css'
})
export class AtributoComponent {
  messageType = 1
}
```

attributte.component.html

```
<p [ngClass]="{'info' : messageType === 1, 'error' : messageType !== 1  }">Mensaje importante</p>
```

Do you know if the import is okay or should I import something else?

Thanks ins advance

Then notice that if I add it works with ngClass but not working with ngStyle

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
   selector: 'app-attribute',
   standalone: true,
   imports: [CommonModule],
   templateUrl: './attribute.component.html',
   styleUrl: './attribute.component.css'
})
```

Comment: Try to import NgClass and NgStyle https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule

Answer (score 0):

`ngClass` & `ngStyle` are directives.

Directives need to be imported in standalone components to be instantiated.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-atributo',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [NClass, NgStyle],
  templateUrl: './atributo.component.html',
  styleUrl: './atributo.component.css'
})
export class AtributoComponent {
  messageType = 1
}
```

Unlink with component with selectors, directive can match anything from attributes to tags. This means the framework doesn't throw an error when a directive is not imported in a standalone component.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<h1 class="font-black uppercase text-6xl md:text-8xl text-center py-8 px-4">
  <div [ngStyle]="true ? { color: 'red' } : { color: 'yellow' }">home page</div>
</h1>
```

**ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.scss']
})
export class HomePageComponent {

}
```

please check this stack blitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-tvhx5n-p1zh8q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhome-page%2Fhome-page.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fhome-page%2Fhome-page.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

ngClass and ngStyle are actual directive need to import before using for Standalone component:

```
import { NgFor, NgClass } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
   selector: 'app-attribute',
   standalone: true,
   imports: [NgFor, NgClass],
   templateUrl: './attribute.component.html',
   styleUrl: './attribute.component.css'
})
```